# How to convert integers to characters in C?

Tags: c, integer, character

For example, if the integer was 97, the character would be 'a', or 98 to 'b'.

Comment: just cast it ? (char)theint? whr the theint in Ascii set and reverse is also possible (int)thechar

Comment: @7-isnotbad: I want an ascii character to be generated from ascii code.

Comment: whats th prob now ? hv u read my comment ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183150/how-do-you-convert-a-decimal-to-corresponding-ascii-character

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C, `int`, `char`, `long`, etc. are all *integers*.

They typically have different memory sizes and thus different ranges as in `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX`.  `char` and arrays of `char` are often used to store characters and strings.  Integers are stored in many types: `int` being the most popular for a balance of speed, size and range.

ASCII is by far the most popular character encoding, but others exist.  The ASCII code for an 'A' is 65, 'a' is 97, '\n' is 10, etc.  ASCII data is most often stored in a `char` variable.  If the C environment is using ASCII encoding, the following all store the same value into the integer variable.

```
int i1 = 'a';
int i2 = 97;
char c1 = 'a';
char c2 = 97;
```

To convert an `int` to a `char`, simple assign:

```
int i3 = 'b';
int i4 = i3;
char c3;
char c4;
c3 = i3;
// To avoid a potential compiler warning, use a cast `char`.
c4 = (char) i4;
```

This warning comes up because `int` typically has a greater range than `char` and so some loss-of-information may occur.  By using the cast `(char)`, the potential loss of info is explicitly directed.

To print the value of an integer:

```
printf("<%c>\n", c3); // prints <b>

// Printing a `char` as an integer is less common but do-able
printf("<%d>\n", c3); // prints <98>

// Printing an `int` as a character is less common but do-able.
// The value is converted to an `unsigned char` and then printed.
printf("<%c>\n", i3); // prints <b>

printf("<%d>\n", i3); // prints <98>
```

There are additional issues about printing such as using `%hhu` or casting when printing an `unsigned char`, but leave that for later.  There is a lot to `printf()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
char c1 = (char)97;  //c1 = 'a'

int i = 98;
char c2 = (char)i;  //c2 = 'b'
```

Answer (score 1):

Casting the integer to a char will do what you want.

```
char theChar=' ';
int theInt = 97;
theChar=(char) theInt;

cout<<theChar<<endl;
```

There is no difference between 'a' and 97 besides the way you interperet them.

Comment: `cout<<theChar<<endl;` is not valid C code.  The rules for C++ differ from C is some regards considering constants, `char` and `int` for this C post.  In C,   `' '` is an `int`.  In C++, it is a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void main ()
 {
    int temp,integer,count=0,i,cnd=0;
    char ascii[10]={0};
    printf("enter a number");
    scanf("%d",&integer);
     if(integer>>31)
     {
     /*CONVERTING 2's complement value to normal value*/    
     integer=~integer+1;    
     for(temp=integer;temp!=0;temp/=10,count++);    
     ascii[0]=0x2D;
     count++;
     cnd=1;
     }
     else
     for(temp=integer;temp!=0;temp/=10,count++);    
     for(i=count-1,temp=integer;i>=cnd;i--)
     {

        ascii[i]=(temp%10)+0x30;
        temp/=10;
     }
    printf("\n count =%d ascii=%s ",count,ascii);

 }
```

Comment: `integer=~integer+1;` is `int` overflow when `integer == INT_MIN`.  This is undefined behavior. This code produced "count =11 ascii=-./,),(-*,..."  `ascii[10]` is too small for many large negative values leading to buffer overrun.

Answer (score 0):

#### Program Converts ASCII to Alphabet

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main ()
{

  int num;
  printf ("=====This Program Converts ASCII to Alphabet!=====\n");
  printf ("Enter ASCII: ");
  scanf ("%d", &num);
  printf("%d is ASCII value of '%c'", num, (char)num );
}
```

#### Program Converts Alphabet to ASCII code

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main ()
{

  char alphabet;
  printf ("=====This Program Converts Alphabet to ASCII code!=====\n");
  printf ("Enter Alphabet: ");
  scanf ("%c", &alphabet);
  printf("ASCII value of '%c' is %d", alphabet, (char)alphabet );
}
```

Comment: The cast in `(char)alphabet` is casting object `alphabet`, which is a `char`, to a `char`.  Certainly the cast is not needed.  `(char)num` is strange and unneeded as passing a `char` as `...` parameter, convert that to an `int`.  The `"%c"` directs the function then to convert that `int` to an `unsigned char` and then prints the character per that value.